# Mapping key values between different size vectors

Tags: scala

I am still new to scala and am having a rough time getting this functionality to work in my code.

I am trying to create a mapping of 24 hours from hour_vector and fill the "visitor" values whenever there is a visitor for the particular hour in the hour_visitors vector

```
val hour_visitors = Vector((10,100),(11,25),(16,200))
val hour_vector = Vector(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)

val map_visitors_to_hours = hour_vector.map(a => a -> hour_visitors(a)._2).toMap.withDefaultValue(0)
```

This does not work as I am getting index out of bounds error (which makes sense).

However if I replace:

```
val map_visitors_to_hours = hour_vector.map(a => a -> hour_visitors(1)._2).toMap.withDefaultValue(0)
```

This will map every value from the 1st index of hour_visitor.

I can re-map the values from hour_index to a list but that defeats the idea, as I am losing the "hour" key in that instance and the values will be inserted incorrectly into the 24 hour vector.

How can I use standard library to map the values from 1 vector into another only when the keys exist in both vectors and if they are not present in 1 vector then output a value of 0.

In python I could just use a merge on 2 dataframes with all.x or all.y, this scala approach is still quite confusing for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to make `hour_visitors` a `Map` and use `getOrElse` to fetch values for the hours in `hour_vector` as shown below

```
val map_hour_visitors = hour_visitors.toMap

val map_visitors_to_hours = hour_vector.map( h =>
    (h, map_hour_visitors.getOrElse(h, 0))
  ).toMap
// map_visitors_to_hours: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(
//   0 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 10 -> 100, 14 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 1 -> 0, 6 -> 0, 21 -> 0,
//   9 -> 0, 13 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 17 -> 0, 22 -> 0, 12 -> 0, 7 -> 0, 3 -> 0,
//  18 -> 0, 16 -> 200, 11 -> 25, 23 -> 0, 8 -> 0, 19 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 15 -> 0
// )
```

Comment: This is it! I can follow the logic but working this out on myself would be quite difficult, just seems like so many toMap calls to get something so trivial to work properly (perhaps it isnt as trivial as I think it is)

Comment: @user3674993, from performance point of view, I'd say the first `toMap` is well worth it as you get `O(1)` in `Map` lookup.  As to the other `toMap`, it can be skipped if your data specs allow the result to be in `Vector[(Int, Int)]`.